# jQuery AJAX loaded content slideshow

Tags: jquery

I have created a slideshow to go on a zencart site. The slidehow page is an external file that is loaded via AJAX. Please find the code snippet below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //Load the slideshow page       
    jQuery("#slidershow").load("/xxxxxxxxxx/index.php?main_page=page&id=2 #slider");

    //Targetting live content, #slider is loaded via AJAX
    jQuery("#slider").live("click" ,function(){jQuery(this).s3Slider({timeOut:5000});});


});
```

Instead of live("click"...) I would like it to appear onload automatically.. But live() does not support "load". What other ways I could get the plugin to trigger onload? hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the callback function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //Load the slideshow page       
    jQuery("#slidershow").load("/the-url.php #slider", function () {
        // as soon as the ajax content is loaded, start the slideshow:
        jQuery(this).s3Slider({timeOut:5000});
    });

});
```